# Intellij IDEA threading issue

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea

I have a problem with IDEA 2016.2.2
I wrote a threading demo with flying ball

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Ball extends JFrame implements Runnable{
    private DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
    private int b_x; // ball's x
    private int b_y; // ball's y
    private int b_d; // ball's diameter
    private Thread thread = null;
    private JButton button;
    private boolean flag = false;

    private Ball(){
        initGUI();
        b_x = b_y = b_d = 50;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    private void initGUI(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Ball Thread Demo");
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        button = new JButton("Start");
        this.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            button.setText(flag ? "Start" : "Stop");
            flag = !flag;
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            //System.out.println();
            if(flag) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                b_x += 1;
                b_y += 1;
                drawPanel.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

        class DrawPanel extends JPanel{
            @Override
            protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            }

            @Override
            protected void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHint(
                        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2d.setColor(new Color(247, 123, 40));
                g2d.fillOval(b_x, b_y, b_d, b_d);
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Ball().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

So, the problem is - if I launch this code via cmd - it works good.
But in IDEA it works only with `System.out.println` that comment out in `run` method, another way nothing is happened. Is that an issue of this IDE or I am missing smth important?

Comment: can you add the DrawPanel class with the minimum code which is needed to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @hunter I can, but I think it does not make much sense, whatever, I add.

Comment: i am interested to reproduce this problem, i am using the same IDEA version

Comment: anyway do a simple test,in IDEA before you start to run your app, open the run configuration and change the JRE to alternative JRE and point to to same JRE you used to run the app in CMD

Comment: @hunter get it. I send my code to a friend - he have same problem.

Comment: Could you imports to the code?

Comment: @Meo k. I placed whole source code

Comment: Ok, reproduced. Nice.

Comment: i was unable to reproduce that, what is the JRE that you are using?

Comment: @hunter javac 1.8.0_45

Comment: sorry i dont have this JRE at the moment, i tried with 1.8.0_20, works like a charm, i can see a orange ball smoothly traveling from left top corner to right bottom corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b_x`, `b_y` and `flag` need to be made `volatile`, since they are updated and read in different threads.

Comment: from thread + swing perspective , this application has problem, it even tries to paint from a non EDT thread. but thats not the main problem he faced, he cannot run this app in IDEA but can be run in CMD

Comment: It is just a matter of JVM magic. When `flag` is not volatile, then the loop will never notice that it is true, for some reason printing or even sleeping prevent such runtime optimization.

Comment: And by the way, it does not work for me properly even from the command line.

Comment: ah ok , then OP might be using two different JRE.as you said optimization might depend on the JRE, did making the flag volatile solve the problem?